# Calculating similarity between two vectors/Strings in R

Tags: r, pattern-matching, similarity, cosine-similarity, stringdist

It might be similar question asked in this forum but I feel my requirement peculiar.
I have a data frame df1 where it consists of variable "WrittenTerms"  with 40,000 observations and I have another data-fame df2 with variable "SuggestedTerms" with 17,000 observations

I need to calculate the similarity  between  "written Term" and "suggestedterms"

df1$WrittenTerms

head pain

lung cancer

abdminal pain

df2$suggestedterms

cardio attack

breast cancer

abdomen pain

head ache

lung cancer

**I need to get the output as  follow**

**df1$WrittenTerms    df2$suggestedterms   Similarity_percentage**

head pain               head ache           50%

lung cancer           lung cancer           100%

abdminal pain          abdomen pain          80%

I am writing the below code to meet the requirement but its taking more time as it involves for loop and is there any way where we can find similarity using TF IDF OR any other approach which will take less time

```
df_list <- data.frame(check.names = FALSE) # Creating empty dataframe

# calculating similarity between strings.

for(i in df1$WrittenTerms){
  df2$oldsim<- stringdist(i,df2$suggestedterms,method = "lv")
  df2$oldsim <- 1 - df2$oldsim / nchar(as.character(df2$suggestedterms))
  df2 <- head(df2[order(df2$oldsim, decreasing = TRUE),],1)
  df_list <- rbind(df_list, df2)
}

df1 <- cbind(df1, df_list)
```

Comment: Look into things like cosine similarity or make each line a document term matrix and then compare counts of features.

Answer (score 0):

The base library's `adist` function gives you Levenshtein distances between two arrays, returning a matrix of distances for each pair of entries. You could write a function that converts the Levenshtein metric into your transformation:

```
my_dist <- function(x, y) 1 - adist(x, y) / nchar(y)
x <- my_dist(df1$WrittenTerms, df2$suggestedterms)
```

Now obtain the maximum value of your metric for each row of x, which will be the best `suggestedterm` for each `WrittenTerms`:

```
mx <- apply(x, 1, function(y) {mx <- which.max(y); c(y[mx], mx)})
```

Your final desired data frame could then be constructed as follows:

```
data.frame(Written.Terms = df1$WrittenTerms, 
           suggestedterms = df2$suggestedterms[mx[2, ]], 
           Similarity_percentage = mx[1, ])
```

Comment: Thanks, but this approach is taking a lot of time to compute the similarity percentage as my data frame contains 40000 observations. Could you please share an approach it it can be done through TFIDF concept